# Ipython notebook lauch being failed

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I try to run ipython notebook at my terminal. The browser opens with /localhost:8888/tree on the address bar but fail to load the interface instead it keeps on loading the page. Moreover my terminal keeps on printing the following block of code over and over again.

I have UN-installed zmq many times but in vain. I have used Ipython from different sources like ubuntu servers/ github repository but the same problem persisted.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 330, in start
  self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
  KeyError: 3
  ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 3
```

One reason for this behavior was pointed out by a cool guy at #python channel at freenode (I forgot his nick) that my packages are messed up due to repeated use of PIP and Apt simultaneously before this situation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would remove all remnants of the notebook and then reinstall using one method, you have tried  `pip install -U pyzmq `?

Comment: I have already started using one only method of installation(actually I have unistalled pip as well.) that is using apt and have used snaptic to remove every thing related to notebook and then have reinstalled in vain.

Comment: you have installed `pyzmq` yes?

Comment: should I try pip install -U pyzmq???

Comment: ok run `sudo pip install -U pyzmq`

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Is it wise to use pip and apt both for the installtion with sudo??

Comment: I use Ubuntu and always use pip to install python packages which is what `pyzmq` is, how did you install ipython notebook?

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I had to reinstall pip again. It would be nice if you can write it as an answer, since I have seen one other thread here mentioning the same problem with no comments or answers.

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. Keep pip for installing your python packages.

Comment: @sohaik. Added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pyzmq.

`sudo pip install pyzmq`